# NPM coverage threshold - settings

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bamboo

I am running npm coverage test and would like to set the coverage threshold. May i know how to do it ???

I am currently running it as a bamboo plan as something like below :-

```
cd ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/XXX
npm install react-scripts
npm run coverage
```

I would like to add the Coverage threshold here. Could you please help me on this ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the `create-react-app` [guide](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#configuration) for coverage configuration, since it uses `react-scripts` under the hood. From the docs:

> The default Jest coverage configuration can be overridden by adding any of the following supported keys to a Jest config in your package.json.

Basically, add the config under `jest` property in your `package.json`, something like

```
"jest": {
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "global": {
      "branches": 90,
      "functions": 90,
      "lines": 90,
      "statements": 90
    }
  }
}
```